# Cypress / Visual Studio Code / Cypress failed to start

Tags: visual-studio-code, cypress

I am junior QA Tester, started working with Cypress and IDE Visual Studio, after updating Cypress 5.2.0, I got a strange error like the following:

```
It looks like this is your first time using Cypress: 5.2.0

  ✖  Verifying Cypress can run /Users/viktoriiahanke/Library/Caches/Cypress/5.2.0/Cypress.app
    → Cypress Version: 5.2.0
Cypress failed to start.

This is usually caused by a missing library or dependency.

The error below should indicate which dependency is missing.

https://on.cypress.io/required-dependencies

If you are using Docker, we provide containers with all required dependencies installed.

----------

Command was killed with SIGKILL (Forced termination): /Users/viktoriiahanke/Library/Caches/Cypress/5.2.0/Cypress.app/Contents/MacOS/Cypress --no-sandbox --smoke-test --ping=563

----------

Platform: darwin (19.6.0)
Cypress Version: 5.2.0
```

I have already tried to delete Cypress and install it with npm from the beginning, but Cypress itself is working, when I download it manually , but when I try to start it in console or in Visual Studio Console it is not opening, writing me that I miss dependencies like above.

Did anyone have such problem before?

Comment: Yeah, other people experienced this type of error before. See https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3176

Comment: Thanks )) I found a solution here. Best Regards, Viktoriia

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in the terminal `export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`
and then try installing again.

Answer (score 0):

I think it had been updated from a previous version, 3.1.3.  Go into cache and delete all versions of cypress then re-install.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that there are missing some vital folders/files like integration, cypress.json... Try to run the 'npm install' command in the terminal for installing the dependencies.

Also, maybe if you start from an existing project, it will be fine (run npm install command also).